# JaxB - Setting HexBinary values

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to call a simple XML over HTTP service by using spring and jaxb. The service has one of its request attribtues as 
<xsd:attribute name="version" type="xsd:hexBinary" use="required"/>

JAXB generates the corresponding java wrapper object as

```
/**
 * Gets the value of the version property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public byte[] getVersion() {
    return version;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the version property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public void setVersion(byte[] value) {
    this.version = ((byte[]) value);
}
```

Here, my version is actually a long internally although the service defined it as hexbinary. I don't have control over the service implementation to convert the type from hexbinary to unsignedint.

While making a request to the service, I like to set the version number as myBean.setVersion(12 as bytes) where 12 is just a long number. How do I convert long to byte[] to be able to call setVersion();

Thanks,
Siva.

Comment: Can anyone give an example on converting a long to hexbinary.

Answer (score 2):

```
byte[] longToBytes(long value) {
    final byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
    for (int i = bytes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        bytes[i] = (byte)(value & 0xFF);
        value >>>= 8;
    }
}
```

The default binding for `byte[]` is `xsd:base64Binary`.

You can change it like

```
@XmlElement
@XmlSchemaType(name="hexBinary")
public byte[] getVersion() {
    return version;
}
```